# CLI Method of Provisioning an Ubuntu VM for ESXi 5

Tags: vmware-esxi, command-line-interface, ubuntu-14.04

I'm looking for instructions on how to spin up an Ubuntu 14.04 vm on ESXi using nothing but the CLI on the ESX server.

How would I go about doing that?

I have a *.iso file already on the ESXi server 
This version of ESXi has no Web GUI for power up/down of VMs

The ubuntu OVF is also not compatible. (That's what the error tells me when running OFVTool)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this directly on the host, at least not without some dirty tricks. Anyway, I wouldn't do it... console / ssh are mainly for troubleshooting.

I'd advise you to use something like [PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/), [Ruby vSphere Console](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/rvc) or [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) from a management station.